# Gitlab with apache proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, gitlab

I have an apache2 server running on a Mac OS X machine with the same machine running Gitlab virtually in Ubuntu.

Mac IP: 192.168.0.7

Ubuntu (virtual) IP: 192.168.0.12

I would like apache to make gitlab.mydomain.com to go to the Ubuntu virtual machine while anythingelse.mydomain.com go to the Mac.

I added a file (gitlab.mydomain.conf) to `/private/etc/apache2/other/` (on the Mac) with the following contents

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gitlab.mydomain.com
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.12
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.12
  ProxyPreserveHost On

</VirtualHost>
```

The gitlab.yml on the Ubuntu virtual machine file contains

```
##Gitlab settings
gitlab:
  ## Web server settings
  host: gitlab.mydomain.com
  port: 80
  https: false
```

When I go to `gitlab.mydomain.com` I get the following error:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /users/sign_in.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: 192.168.0.12users
```

But if I go to `192.168.0.12` I get the Gitlab sign in page.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Can someone with enough reputation add a Gitlab tag to this question?

Answer (score 4):

try

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gitlab.mydomain.com
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.12/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.12/
  ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

From [mod_proxy ProxyPass docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

```
If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument
should also end with a trailing / and vice versa. Otherwise the
resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and
do not deliver the expected results.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't searched enough.

1. You will need to edit file `/home/gitlab/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb`
2. Find line listen `"#{app_dir}/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket"` and comment it. Uncomment line `listen "192.168.0.12:80"`
3. Enable the apache module `proxy` with `sudo a2enmod proxy`
4. Enable the apache module `proxy_http` with `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`
5. Add this to your virtual host

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName gitlab.mydomain.com

   # Custom log file locations
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_access.log combined

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.12/
   <Location />
       ProxyPassReverse /
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Location>
   ```
6. Restart gitlab & apache
7. Have fun.

https://gist.github.com/steve-todorov/4758707

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming from google this is what worked on Ubuntu 18.04, apache 2.4.2 and Gitlab enterprise edition 12.8.5.
I followed the following link [using-a-non-bundled-web-server](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server)

Skipped step 3 as my apache was on the same server and downloaded the correct vhost from Step 5 for Apache 2.4.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.